# App to monitor WinServices

Tags: c#, windows-services, monitoring

I have a couple of WinServices that run some functionality (not apps) through using timers. I need to create an application that should monitor the activity of those services - start/pause, view services status, get some activity report (I realize that a part of report functionality I'll need to implement also on service flow).

Could You give some start points in that? or samples?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: heart beat program? see if [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8349/Observing-Applications-via-Heartbeat) is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ServiceController` class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx

This allows you to check the status of a Windows Service, Stop & Start them and [send int commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.executecommand.aspx) into your service to trigger functionality